# views::iota vs ranges::iota_view - "expression equivalent" so why both exist?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges, iota

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
    for (int num: std::ranges::views::iota(0,5)) {
        std::cout << num << 'n';
    }
    
    for (int i : std::ranges::iota_view{55, 65}) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}
```

[CPP Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view)

> 2. `views::iota(e)` and `views::iota(e, f)` are **expression-equivalent** to
>    `iota_view(e)` and `iota_view(e, f)` respectively for any suitable
>    subexpressions `e` and `f`.

Is there any reason to use one vs the other?

And if not, why do they both exist since they were both introduced in C++20?

Answer (score 6):

`std::ranges::iota_view` is the type that behaves like a view that generates its elements ad hoc. It must be somehow constructible.

`std::views::iota` is a helper customization point object that follows a pattern which can yield more performant / correct results when used. It will ultimately return `std::ranges::iota_view`. Said pattern is the usage of `views::something` rather than `ranges::something_view`.

When you nest more adaptors together, using the latter may turn out to produce better results (mainly in terms of compile-time).

In general, [prefer `views::meow`](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2023/03/14/prefer-views-meow/).